# Can't load URI into MediaPlayer to play sound from SD card

Tags: android, button, uri, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard

I select a sound from which to load the URI from SD card using an intent picker

```
Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
loadIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
loadIntent.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(loadIntent.createChooser(loadIntent, "Select Audio"),
                         SOUND_LOAD_REQUEST);}
```

I am able to get data and a URI back in onActivityResult using a few different ways

```
if (requestCode == SOUND_LOAD_REQUEST)
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { //make sure the request was successful
        Uri soundUri1 = data.getData();
        String soundPath = data.getDataString(); 
        Uri soundUri2 = Uri.parse(soundPath);
        pathTwo = soundUri.getEncodedPath();
```

> soundPath yields content://media/external/audio/media/1005
>
> pathTwo yields   /external/audio/media/1005

I have tried taking both URIs from above and both paths from above and loading them into both MediaPlayer and soundPool, and I can't seem to get either to load the sound successfully.

Here is how I load:

```
      mloadedSound = mSoundPool.load(pathTwo, 1);

      mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool mSoundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
                  }
          });
```

or

```
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       try {
             mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pathFive)
             loaded=true;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                loaded=false;
                throw new RuntimeException("Sound did not load");
            }

           if(loaded=true) {mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                           }
```

I get load errors with both of these methods. For soundpool it says "sound did not load" for media player it won't run the code.
I'm not sure whether mediaPlayer or soundPool is better for the application. I'm only loading in a sound from the SD card with one button and playing the sound with a second. I preferred soundPool for its simplicity, but I don't know if it can handle larger mp3 files.

Any suggestions on how to load a URI? When I try to load a URI into the MediaPlayer I get a failed IOException.
Do I have to use contentResolvers, or MediaStore to parse the URI? Any help or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. It seems the error was that in KitKat you have to declare permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".
I wasn't getting this error initially because my onClickListener for the MediaPlayer was in the onCreate method not the OnActivityResultMethod.
I got everything working, and have posted my load button code and my onActivityResultCode below for others who may have this issue.

```
    //Load Sound Button
    final View loader = findViewById(R.id.load_button);
    loader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
            loadIntent.setAction(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            loadIntent.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(createChooser(loadIntent, "Select Audio"), SOUND_LOAD_REQUEST);}
    });

    //End of Load Sound Button
```

&

```
//Start of onActivityResult
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SOUND_LOAD_REQUEST)
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                Uri soundUri = data.getData();  Log.i(TAG, "Intent data" + data.getData().toString());
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, soundUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                //Play Sound Button
                final View mrButton = findViewById(R.id.push_button);
                mrButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    }else{
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                }
            });
            //End of Play Sound Button
        }
}

//End of onActivityResult
```

Happy Coding